# How to do perspective fixing?

Tags: java, math, logic, perspective

I'm searching for a fast way to fix perspective of a picture given in java or any language.And currently i really don't have any idea how to do it, nor find anything useful in Google.

Input:
Point[4] , Color[][]

Output:
Perspective-Fixed Color[][]

By Perspective Fixing, i meant the one in Photoshop. Just Like:

[image]

I^d appreciate it if you tell me how the code piece works since i want to understand the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to just remap coordinates from the original to the final image, copying pixels from one coordinate space to the other, rounding off as necessary -- which may result in some pixels being copied several times adjacent to each other, and other pixels being skipped, depending on whether you're stretching or shrinking (or both) in either dimension. Make sure your copying iterates through the destination space, so all pixels are covered there even if they're painted more than once, rather than thru the source which may skip pixels in the output.

The better solution involves calculating the corresponding source coordinate without rounding, and then using its fractional position between pixels to compute an appropriate average of the (typically) four pixels surrounding that location. This is essentially a filtering operation, so you lose some resolution -- but the result looks a LOT better to the human eye; it does a much better job of retaining small details and avoids creating straight-line artifacts which humans find objectionable.

Note that the same basic approach can be used to remap flat images onto any other shape, including 3D surface mapping.

Comment: BTW, any good book on modern computer graphics is likely to show you this, and a lot more, in greater detail.

Comment: (Many many years ago, I wrote a version of this as part of a "collage" tool, as a student project in the Architecture Machine Group at MIT. Mine allowed painting one picture over another, and had the addition of a transparancy map (and a paint tool to go with it) which let the user select which of the two images was to be retained at any point, allowing fancy cutout shapes.)

Comment: +1: Inverting *perspective* needs more than a free-form transform, but it also needs the technique you described. This may very well be "good enough" for the OP, as it's not too hard and can be implemented to be fast.

Comment: More then looking good to human eye i want more statistical results since im going to perspective fix a monitor's photo and find a objects point on it.Nevertheless, your answer is pretty satisfactory but i need something like psudeo-code since i really dont understand how to do remapping on [][] arrays with given 4 points.

Comment: How much graphics programming background do you have? Do you know how to draw lines between two arbitrary points?

(Though if you want pseudocode I'd start by websearching. There's got to be a page somewhere that describes this in more detail than I'm going to retype from memory and first principles, and they may include the additional complications Jongware was grumbling about. Possible keywords are "surface mapping" for the simple version and "perspective correction algorithm" for something more serious.)

Comment: @keshlam I cant even be counted as beginner Although i really need a function do to perspective correction for me since i really need it for my project and i really don't have any idea how to do it mathematically

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you go looking for an off-the-shelf function library which provides image processing operations...